# DodoEX pools not available via 0x API

Tags: 0x

We have created two one-sided Dodo V2 pools (ethereum/polygon) as part of initial treasury supply and kickoff and they are not showing up in 0x API for swapping.

There should be sufficient buyToken liquidity to conduct the swap.

Pools were created > 24 hours ago.

Ethereum
https://legacy.dodoex.io/pool/list/0x47f01c0cf28fbdd04aac79a40a3c8ddf455a0e6a?network=mainnet

Polygon
https://legacy.dodoex.io/pool/list/0xcf8efab49899e5f7d9cb92bd8ac607192ab00d1e?network=polygon

Comment: Could this be due to DodoEX V2 updating the domain names of their pools?

app.dodoex.io > legacy.dodoex.io

Comment: DODO is showing me that there is no Liquidity in these pools?